# Getting MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll is missing error message on Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows, .net

Not sure if this belongs on serverfault, let me know if it should be posted somewhere else.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

An installation for a corporate .NET app (desktop app that uses .NET 4.5) seems to have messed up the Visual C++ runtime distribution. After the installation I am getting the error message 'The program can't start because MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll is missing from your computer'. I now get this error when trying to run any .NET 4 application.

MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll is a Windows 8 DLL. I am running Windows 7. The installer for the app seems to have installed the Windows 8 version of something related to .NET 4, causing all .NET 4 / 4.5 apps to fail to start, or changed some system settings to Windows 8 related values even though I am running Windows 7.

Additional info:

- The installer was created using InstallShield
- The exact same thing happened on another computer, after that the installation package was pulled.
- The creator of the installation package does not know why this is happening
- .NET 2 apps still run fine on my machine
- I do not have a restore point to go back to. By the time I found a tip about that a new automatic restore point had already been created and for some reason only one restore point was present.

What I have tried:

- Reinstalled the Windows 7 C++ 64-bit redistributable (latest version, update 4)
- Reinstalled .NET 4.5

Does anyone know what I would need to do to get my .NET 4 / 4.5 environment back in working order?

Edit:

This is a particularly nasty issue. I have now uninstalled all the C++ redistributables and reinstalled Visual Studio 2012 and I am still getting the error.

It seems as if the .NET 4 bootstrapping mechanism has been modified to think it is running on a Windows 8 PC, looking for Windows 8 DLLs, even though this is a Windows 7 machine.